# What is the temperature of water vapour itself?

Tags: temperature, water

Assuming standard atmospheric pressure, Does the water vapour created from boiling water have the temp of 100 °C? What about water vapour created by evaporation at room temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an equilibrium state then the answer is "yes" the temperature of the liquid and the vapour will be the same.
In both cases you have a large volume of system to keep at the same temperature.
When you boil some water in a kettle the vapour soon loses heat to the cooler surrounding air and starts to condense back to a liquid.
That is the reason that you can see steam.

Comment: Thanks. Why would the temp be same at equilibrium - given that temp is directly proportional to kinetic energy of molecules and vapor molecules have higher kinetic energy than liquid molecules.

Comment: In the equilibrium state the temperature of liquid and vapour is the same. If that were not the case then there would be a net transfer of heat from one state to the other.

Comment: Ok. do you mean to say average kinetic energy of water vapour molecules is the same as that of liquid molecules, it is in equilibrium with?

Comment: @user13107 Temperature is not kinetic energy. Certainly not in water with all the hydrogens having a lot of zero-point motion.